# How do I get multiple remote desktop connections for a Windows Home Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-home-server

Is it possible to have multiple remote desktop connections to a Windows Home Server. Or do I need to use a full Server product like Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Home Server does not support multiple RDP connections. You will need Windows Server.

If you need more than two connections, you will also need additional licences from Microsoft ([Remote Desktop licences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732684.aspx)).